# Filling a board with maximum number of fixed size tiles

Tags: optimization, discrete-mathematics, backtracking

You are given a rectangular board of known size, e.g. 20x20 cm. Some *1x1 cm* pieces are missing. Your task is to cover this board with a maximum number of *2x2 cm* tiles (an example is attached below), while it's not allowed to cover missing tiles. Currently, I solve it using the following greedy algorithm:

```
for x in N:
  for y in M:
    insert a tile at (x, y) if it possible

    for x1 in N:
      for y1 in M:
        insert a tile at (x1, y1) if it possible

    remove the tile
```

I'm sure that it's not the right way to approach this problem, but it passes all tests that are interesting to me. There is a somewhat [similar problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/divide-and-conquer-set-6-tiling-problem/), but I doubt that I can reuse it in mine settings. I think that it could be solved by backtracking, but I'm stuck at this point.

Example. Orange pieces are missing.

[image]